# referencing tr elements

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery so I apologize if this is a silly question...

```
$('#sortList tr').each(function()
{
    i = $(this).index();
    v = $(this).find('td:first').text();
    n = $(this).find('td:first').html();  
});
```

looping through the rows of a table and getting the index of each row and the text and html of the first cell of each row. All works fine. then I try to get the same for the next row and I find the following...

This works fine... `j = $(this).next().index();`

But this fails... `v = $(this).next().find('td:first').text();`

and this fails... `n = $(this).next().find('td:first').html();`

If `$(this)` and `$(this).next()` both work for `index()` why not `find()`? Aren't they both pointers to a `tr`?

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="sortList" class="pagetext" width="200">
    <tr>
        <td align='left'><a href="Javascript:;;" OnClick="Javascript:Link_OnClick('ACCRUAL','Accrual');return false;">Accrual</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='left'><a href="Javascript:;;" OnClick="Javascript:Link_OnClick('EETAXES','Employee - Taxes');return false;">Employee - Taxes</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='left'><a href="Javascript:;;" OnClick="Javascript:Link_OnClick('EMPVOLDEDS','Employee - Voluntary Deductions');return false;">Employee - Voluntary Deductions</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='left'><a href="Javascript:;;" OnClick="Javascript:Link_OnClick('ERMATCH','Employer - 401(k) Match');return false;">Employer - 401(k) Match</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='left'><a href="Javascript:;;" OnClick="Javascript:Link_OnClick('ERTAXES','Employer - Taxes');return false;">Employer - Taxes</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='left'><a href="Javascript:;;" OnClick="Javascript:Link_OnClick('GTL','Group Term Life');return false;">Group Term Life</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='left'><a href="Javascript:;;" OnClick="Javascript:Link_OnClick('MISC','Miscellaneous');return false;">Miscellaneous</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='left'><a href="Javascript:;;" OnClick="Javascript:Link_OnClick('NETPAY','Net Payroll');return false;">Net Payroll</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='left'><a href="Javascript:;;" OnClick="Javascript:Link_OnClick('TAXFILEE','Tax Filing - Employee Taxes');return false;">Tax Filing - Employee Taxes</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='left'><a href="Javascript:;;" OnClick="Javascript:Link_OnClick('TAXFILER','Tax Filing - Employer Taxes');return false;">Tax Filing - Employer Taxes</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='left'><a href="Javascript:;;" OnClick="Javascript:Link_OnClick('TPCORTAX','Third Party Checks or Tax Checks');return false;">Third Party Checks or Tax Checks</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='left'><a href="Javascript:;;" OnClick="Javascript:Link_OnClick('TPS','Third Party Sick');return false;">Third Party Sick</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='left'><a href="Javascript:;;" OnClick="Javascript:Link_OnClick('WAGE','Wage');return false;">Wage</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: are you using rowspans at all? can you show your HTML for the table?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/each/ you don't need to define the index, it's already there

Comment: also, if it's the last row in the table, then of course it would fail because there are no TDs in the resultant jQuery object returned from $(this).next()

Comment: have you tried using `.children('td:first')`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sJUZR/1/ -- Working for me I believe...could you be more specific on your error? Also, can you post your HTML table code please.

Comment: By faild I mean the function dies at that line of v =

Comment: There are many rows in the table and it dies on the first one. Trying to post HTML of table now but having trouble figuring out how to get it into the editor.

Comment: Works for me yet: http://jsfiddle.net/sJUZR/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what's wrong with your code, but this tidied up version works:

```
$('#sortList tr').each(function(rowIndex) {
    var $row = $(this),
        $nextRow = $row.next(),
        $td, j, v, n;

    $td = $row.find('td:first');
    j = rowIndex;
    v = $td.text();
    n = $td.html();

    console.log('this row: ' + j + '\t' + v + '\t' + n);

    if ($nextRow.length > 0) {
        $td = $nextRow.find('td:first');
        j = rowIndex + 1; // duh?
        v = $td.text();
        n = $td.html();
        console.log('next row: ' + j + '\t' + v + '\t' + n);
    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VxSZf/2/

Comment: This ended up being a FF issue with the text(). I wrapped the text in a span and everything works fine now. Very annoying. Thanks for the help.